# Abat-jour, c'est un volet plein ou en persienne

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, usage, histoire, menuiserie

*Le Dictionnaire Pratique de Menuiserie - Ebénisterie - Charpente*

*Par J. Justin Storck, édition de 1900*

est **la** référence pour tous ceux qui s'intéressent pour la menuiserie. Regardons ensemble le lexique **abat-jour** ([qui est par hasard disponible librement en ligne, peut-être abrégé](http://justinstorck.free.fr/a/abat-jour.php)):

> Abat-jour subs. masc. I. Men. Appareil en partie pleine emboîtée ou d'assemblage, placé au devant des fenêtres de prison pour empêcher toute communication avec le dehors (fig. 39). II. Volet plein ou en persienne que l'on place devant les portes ou fenêtres des habitations pour arrêter les rayons du soleil ou en diminuer l'ardeur (Voy. Devanture et Saillie).

Les français ont fortement dénié et désavoué le sens II ci-dessus dans [ma question dernière](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31660/can-i-say-jalousie-instead-of-store). Rappelons quelques commentaires comme

> I never used or even heard *abat-jour* for anything but a lamp shade.

**Que pensez-vous? Est-ce que vous avez déjà entendu ou utilisé "abat-jour" dans un sens pareil, soit-il dans un cadre profesionnel ou quotidien ? Est-ce que ce sens est archaïque ? Les experts dans la menuiserie sont invité à repondre... Merci à tous !**

Comment: non, je n'ai jamais entendu ce mot dans un autre sens que la partie supérieure d'une lampe qui sert à diriger le flux lumineux vers le bas (je ne suis pas expert de la menuiserie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le terme est apparu en français en 1670 selon le *Dictionnaire culturel en langue française* de Robert. Il décrit deux dispositifs, dont le premier redirige la lumière pour aider à éclairer des endroits sombres (des volet en persiennes conviendraient à cet usage) et le second pour empêcher de voir ou d’être vu (auquel cas un volet plein apparaît plus probable). On accompage ce deuxième exemple d’une citation de Stendhal, tirée de *La Chartreuse de Parme* :

> Je voulais la prier de daigner toujours, en soignant ses oiseaux, regarder quelquefois la fenêtre de la prison, même quand elle la trouvera masquée par un énorme volet de bois : je voulais lui indiquer que je ferai tout ce qui est humainement possible pour parvenir à la voir. Grand Dieu ! est-ce qu’elle ne viendra pas demain à cause de ce geste indiscret ? Cette crainte, qui troubla le sommeil de Fabrice, se vérifia complètement le lendemain ; Clélia n’avait pas paru à trois heures, quand on acheva de poser devant les fenêtres de Fabrice les deux énormes **abat-jour** [...]

On mentionne par la suite une nouvelle acception, apparue vers 1800, qui est le sens le mieux compris aujourd’hui (on le mentionne d’ailleurs dans le dictionnaire cité), soit celui d’un réflecteur pour rabattre la lumière d’une lampe, puis par analogie toute disposition protégeant du jour, pour lequel on cite Maupassant dans *Fort comme la mort* :

> Elle s’éloigna, se rapprocha, fit un **abat-jour** de sa main [...]

---

Il y a donc doublon, et il me semble qu’à moins d’être un spécialiste des abat-jour en menuiserie, ou de consulter à cet effet un manuel spécialisé, la signification comprise au premier abord par ce terme sera celle d’un déflecteur de lumière sur une lampe.

Ceci n’empêche en rien de désigner l’abat-jour volet par son nom propre. Il conviendra simplement, dans la plupart des cas, de spécifier de prime abord ce que l’on désigne par ce terme.